# How to calculate integral $\int_{0}^{s}\frac{1+x^{a+1}}{x^a}dx$

Tags: calculus

Can you help me calculate this integral $\int_{0}^{s}\dfrac{1+x^{a+1}}{x^a}dx$, where $a>0$.

And how to do it in matlab.

I tried to do in matlab but there was error, maybe x.^a is not suitable in matlab!

Please help me!

Comment: The integrand is $x^{-a}+x$. The definite integral will not exist if $a\ge 1$. But for $a\lt 1$, it is a short calculation.

Answer (score 2):

Decompose your fraction in $ x^{-a} + x$, then pay attention to the case $a=1$

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\int_{0}^{s}\dfrac{1+x^{a+1}}{x^a}dx$$ contains a partial fraction, in which degree of numberator is greater than denominator, break this up via long division of polynomial, explicitly,

$1+x^{a+1} \div x^a = x - x^{-a}$

Now we have simply the polynomial to something we can integrate,

$$\int_{0}^{s}x - x^{-a}dx$$

This can then be broken to few cases depending on the value of $a$ as mentioned by Andre Nicolas in the comment section.